# Semantic UI sidebar in Vuejs webpack environment

Tags: jquery, webpack, vue.js, semantic-ui

I am using VueJS webpack template.

I am struggling with my sidebar in Semantic UI. Can someone point out what's wrong with my code. It toggles the sidebar, but when I click on the icon again, it doesn't hide the sidebar, instead I can see a weird blink.

```
<template>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="ui right demo vertical sidebar labeled icon menu" id="mobile-sidebar">
  <a class="item">
    <i class="sticky note icon"></i>
    Bulletin
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="newspaper icon"></i>
    News
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="mail icon"></i>
    Contact us
  </a>
</div>

<div class="ui fixed inverted main menu mobile-menu">
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="item">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="right menu">

      <a class="launch icon item" id="mobile-menu-trigger" v-on:click="toggle">
        <i class="content icon"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pusher">
  <h1>
    Hello Vue
  </h1>
</div>
</template>


<script>
     export default {
        name: 'home',
        methods: {
            toggle: function () {
               $('#mobile-sidebar').sidebar('toggle')
            }
        }
     }

</script>
```

Comment: There is no #mobile-sidebar element in your code.

Comment: Can you post a fuller code sample? This paste only appears to be the vue.js component, but doesn't include the markup for the sidebar.

Comment: Added code instead of pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having been struggling a while I managed to fix the problem eventually:

```
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'nav-bar',
    data: function () {
        return {
            isToggled: false,
            sideBar: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
         toggle: function () {
             if (this.isToggled) {
                 this.sideBar.sidebar('hide')
             } else {
                 this.sideBar.sidebar('show')
             }
         }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.sideBar = $('#mobile-sidebar')
        let self = this
        this.sideBar.sidebar({
            transition: 'push',
            onHidden: function () {
                self.isToggled = false
            },
            onShow: function () {
                self.isToggled = true
            }
        })
   }
   }
 </script>
```